# Google-Apps-Script template not creating window or other ui elements

Tags: google-apps-script

I have an unbelievably basic problem. Running a Google apps script template that should create and show a UI does not do so.

I'm using windows 7 and an up to date version of chrome as of 6/3/13.

The script template shows a message that it is running, but never shows a window or any other UI element. The code from the automatic template for creating a web app is entirely unmodified and as follows:

```
// Script-as-app template.
function doGet() {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication();

  var button = app.createButton('Click Me');
  app.add(button);

  var label = app.createLabel('The button was clicked.')
                 .setId('statusLabel')
                 .setVisible(false);
  app.add(label);

  var handler = app.createServerHandler('myClickHandler');
  handler.addCallbackElement(label);
  button.addClickHandler(handler);

  return app;
}

function myClickHandler(e) {
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();

  var label = app.getElementById('statusLabel');
  label.setVisible(true);

  app.close();
  return app;
}
```

As far as I can tell this code should create a basic test window when run. It does not do so, but also throws no errors and shows as running. I have no idea why this problem exists. I would appreciate any help that would allow me to even create a blank window successfully.

Comment: There is a code review exchange site. http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ If it was me, I would find a simple example on the web. Paste it in, run it, change it 50% at a time to make it close to what you have here. Or use logs/debugger.

Comment: For anyone that is wondering, you apparently cannot use the run button to execute the UI portions of a google apps script. In order to execute those portions you must deploy it as a web app after using the manage versions function to select a version. The main question I have now is, "Why did they include a run button and option if it doesn't work for UI functions?"

Comment: Suggest you post the answer in the answer box.

Comment: Had to wait for the time limit on answering my own question.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the problem was that you cannot use the run button to execute the UI portions of a google apps script within their editor. In order to execute those portions you must deploy the script as a web app after using the manage versions function to select a version.